# Select statement not outputting

Tags: mysql

I am trying to do a join in mysql, but the select statement appears to not work. There are two tables, defined at http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/45481/1, and a query that is:

```
select ROUND(sum(sales.amount*exchange.rate),2) 
  AS total from sales 
  INNER JOIN exchange 
  ON sales.currency = exchange.currency;
```

How do you write this query to output the `total` column?

Comment: Your query output 1552 for me.

Comment: Put the `select` statement in the box on the right in SQL Fiddle. Also got 1552

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its running on the Fiddle link that you have given.
The output is 1552.

Try putting the select statement in the right pane.

Comment: Right. Thanks. :) will accept answer as soon as I can.